# Simple d3.js sample chart to get started

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, svg, d3.js

I have looking through all the chart examples on the d3.js site but it's too much complex to understand.
All i want is to plot x axis and y axis and plot a json data like

```
{count:100,year:1999}
{count:240,year:2010}
{count:290,year:2009}
```

Count on x axis and year on y axis.Can any one provide a simple sample to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two sandboxs are helpful for understanding d3 - http://phrogz.net/js/d3-playground/#VerticalBars_HTML (although some examples don't work anymore) and http://enjalot.com - Tributary.

Here is the start of a bar chart based on your data : http://enjalot.com/inlet/4125640/

Comment: dat looks really easy enough.I have a doubt how to control the gap between the year bars.I mean the gap between the Bars of 2 particular years

Comment: Try changing bar_width using the slider in tributary to play around with the values.  It's cool!  For a more complex example: http://horses.phoebebright.com/registrations.html  - the code is in shared.js in the drawYears function.

Comment: And is dere any way to add axis values to both x axis and y axis

Comment: Try this tutorial to understand how to apply axes: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with nvd3

```
  [{values: 
              [{"value":3,"label":"17 hr"},
               {"value":2,"label":"18 hr"},
               {"value":1,"label":"19 hr"}]
    }];
```

Here label is the x axis and value is the y axis

Comment: I think d3 and nvd3 are almost the same graph javascript libraries

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [this](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html) tutorial? It seems to break it down fairly simply, going from a rudimentary chart to a more complex svg example. Once those seem to make sense, you could try replacing the **data** variable with your JSON and go from there.